# Get specific label (incl. data) of k-means

Tags: matlab, k-means, image-segmentation

first of all, I'd like to describe my issue with the kmeans in Matlab.
I select a point via mouse and use it for cluster initialization. This works fine.

After the segmentation of the data, I reshape the data back into proper style, because I need a matrix.
Now I want to select only the cluster of which the user selected the data via mouse.
Therefore I select the index of the mouse-coordinates to select the label, which I want to segmentate. Because of other extra data which is not connected or nearby the relevant data, but also gots the same label.

I want to select only connected-components in a neighbourhood of 8.

So here is my code snippet so far:

```
flatimg = double(reshape(croppedimg,size(croppedimg,1)*size(croppedimg,2),size(croppedimg,3)));
% kmeans
[idx, clusters] = kmeans(flatimg,2,'start',[seedpoint1(3);seedpoint2(3)]);
% form it back to a matrix
k=reshape(idx,size(croppedimg,1),size(croppedimg,2)); 
%convert point, which is part of the label I want to linear index
selectedobjectpoint = sub2ind(size(croppedimg),seedpoint1(2),seedpoint1(1));
hgplabel = k(selectedobjectpoint); 
idx_object = find(k, hgplabel);
% also tried: idx_object = find(k == hgplabel);
```

I added a screenshot, which shows the direct output of `kmeans`:
[image: kmeans output]
So my aim is it here to get only the "white" OR the "black" ones.

Help or advice appreciated. If you've got any questions regarding the snippet or the goal, feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the FIND command is throwing you off.  You want something like:

```
logicalImage = k == hgplabel;
bwImg = bwlabel(logicalImage);
imagesc(bwImg)
```

FIND will output the indices where k == hgplabel.  You want the matrix of zeros and ones where k takes that value (I think).

If you just want the connected components of that, the output of bwlabel will contain unique integers for each connected component, so imagesc(bwImg == 1) will show just component 1.  And you can specify the connectivity

Comment: that's absolutely correct. As the end result I'd like to have only the connected/nearby neighbours of label X in a binary format.

Comment: See the new edit; that should be what bwlabel does.  Also see regionprops.

Comment: yes, i know what it does. but how can i get the connected components?
I only see the clustering by the k-classes, which i want to reduce to parts of a cluster which are nearby/connected to each other.

Comment: Define "get the connected components" - what does that mean?  bwImg will contain unique integers corresponding to each "connected component", so you need to explain what you mean...

Comment: thanks for your help... after a long debug-session I found out that I made a mistake by selecting the wrong label.